# Modifying the Django dynamic forms application to use MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-forms, pymongo

How can I modify the Django dynamic forms application to use MongoDB instead of the default database? Is this even possible?

Comment: What do your mean dynamic forms plugin? Please elaborate more regarding your question. Have you tried http://mongoengine.org/ ?

Comment: Meant https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dynamic-forms . Haven't tried that. Not sure what else to say about it.